# How to remove nodejs from nodesource.com?

Tags: nodejs

I have installed nodejs from nodesource.com:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -

sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

It installed `nodejs 0.12.4`, but how can i remove it now including all footprints from that repo?

I can see a file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First you can purge `nodejs` and its related files

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

then you can delete the its repositoy

```
sudo rm -r  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

Comment: That's all? Nothing more?

Comment: @Heihachi yes that's is

Answer (score 6):

As addition, you may want to remove nodesource key.

First you can see:

```
sudo apt-key list
```

And it will output something look like this

```
pub   4096R/68576280 2014-06-13
uid                  NodeSource <gpg@nodesource.com>
sub   4096R/AA01DA2C 2014-06-13
```

Then you can delete with:

```
sudo apt-key del 68576280
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

But this won't delete the `/usr/lib/node_modules` directory as its not empty.

So for a complete clean up, run:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/node_modules/
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```